# Slideshow-banner (effect: easing images out through canvas border)

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, slideshow, banner

I'm trying to create a banner such as the above mentioned by constantly swapping out 2 images and using them as `fillStyle` (pattern) on a buffer canvas. The idea is to have image1 trail behind image2 with as many pixels as the width of the canvas, and update their position simultaneously on the buffer canvas before drawing on the canvas visible on my page. And of course, when one image moves out of the border, a new source for that image is set while its x position is set to negative as many pixels as the width of the canvas.

The values I'm using for x_incr might seem mysterious, but they're just temporary, arbitrary values that makes for a smooth, increasing speed as I haven't yet found any better way to simulate that effect.

I had it working with 1 image, but now that I added another, my canvas is constantly black while script is running. Why is this happening? And am I going about this all wrong? Might it be better obtained/maintained with CSS3 transformations?

I'm pretty new to all of the languages that I'm using here, but I've tried to follow the standards I know.

Please let me know if parts of the following code is redundant in regards to my question.

Thanks in advance!

JavaScript:

```
var pattern1;
var pattern2;
var x1 = 0.1;
var x2 = 0.1;
var x1_incr = 0.1;
var x2_incr = 0.1;
var canvas = null;
var context = null;
var bufferCanvas = null;
var bufferCanvasCtx = null;
var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = new Image();
var currentImg = 0;
var imgArray = [
    "images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg", "images/4.jpg"
];

function Init () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas1');
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    bufferCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    bufferCanvasCtx = bufferCanvas.getContext("2d");
    bufferCanvasCtx.canvas.width = context.canvas.width;
    bufferCanvasCtx.canvas.height = context.canvas.height;

    loadPattern(img1, pattern1);
    loadPattern(img2, pattern2);

    SwitchImage(img1);

    Draw();

    setInterval(Animate, 10);
}

function loadPattern(image, pattern) {
    image.onload = function () {
        pattern = bufferCanvasCtx.createPattern(image, "no-repeat");
    };
}

function SwitchImage(obj) {
    obj.setAttribute('src', imgArray[currentImg++]);
    if (currentImg >= imgArray.length) {
        currentImg = 0;
    }
}

function Animate () {
    Update(img1, x1, x1_incr);
    Update(img2, x2, x2_incr);
    Draw();
}

function Update (image, x, x_incr) {
    x_incr += 0.1;
    x += x_incr;

    if (x > context.canvas.width) {
        SwitchImage(image);
        x = -context.canvas.width;
        x_incr = 0.1;
    }   
}

function Draw() {
    context.save(); 

    if (x1 < x2) {
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillStyle = pattern1;
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillRect(x1, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillStyle = pattern2;
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillRect(x2, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 
    }
    else {
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillStyle = pattern2;
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillRect(x2, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillStyle = pattern1;
        bufferCanvasCtx.fillRect(x1, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 
    }

    context.drawImage(bufferCanvas, 0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); 
    context.restore();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <LINK href="mypage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body onload="Init()">
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="Canvas1" class="slideshow">Your browser does not support canvas.</canvas>
        </div>
        <script src="mypage.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

.slideshow {
    background-color: lightGray;
    height: 90px;
    width: 728px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: _Any_ feedback will be greatly appreciated!